# gVim - force linebreaks in large file

Tags: vim, formatting, gvim

I pasted a rather large chunk of XML into gVim (on Windows) to edit it. The tool the generates the XML does not put in any linebreaks so the XML pastes as a single line, which makes it rather hard to read/edit/verify. I tried the usual formatting trick `gg=G`, but this does nothing, probably because it's not bad formatting to have everything on a single line. Is there a quick and easy way to *force* the linebreaks and formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of using xmllint, I found I could clean it up with 2 regular expressions:

```
:s/></>\r</g
:%s/<\(.*\)>\n\s*<\/\1>/<\1><\/\1>
```

and THEN run `gg=G`.  The purpose of the second regex is to fix things like:

```
<a>
</a>
```

and turn them into `<a></a>`

Seems to work OK and I can't find any lost/mangled data.
I guess I could make that whole thing into a macro or something...

Answer (score 0):

```
:s/>/\r>/g
```

*then* G=gg

Comment: Hmm not bad, but now the value of each element is on a new line with the closing tag. I was hoping for something like "<a>value</a>", but I get "<a> **\r** value</a>"